# Linux + Solaris how to verify the last execute process from list of process

Tags: linux, shell-script, solaris, ps

I need advice:

How to verify which is the last scan_sys.sh process that run in my linux or solaris ?

my target is to kill all scan_sys.sh process , except the latest scan_sys.sh ( the last execute /usr/scan_sys.sh script )

```
ps -ef | grep scan_sys.sh
```

.

```
root   367     1   0   Nov 08 ?           0:21 /usr/scan_sys.sh
root 27517 27515   0 17:27:18 ?           0:01 /usr/scan_sys.sh
root 18939   367   0   Nov 15 ?           0:00 /usr/scan_sys.sh
root 18940 18939   0   Nov 15 ?           0:01 /usr/scan_sys.sh
root 27515   367   0 17:27:18 ?           0:00 /usr/scan_sys.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ps` option `-o` to select fields you want to display to show process pid, start time and command name, optionally selecting the processes you're interested in right away (`-C`), sort on start time, kill all but the last one.

Since `ps` is notoriously known to be a command line options hell, you'll have to check the man page for your implementation. For me the equivalent of the following works on linux (to list the appropriate PIDs):

```
ps -C scan_sys.sh -o pid --sort start | sed '$d'
```

Remember to quote the `$` in `sed` script with single quotes (at least in `bash`) as otherwise it will be expanded to environment variable `d`. You can send the PIDs to kill e.g. via xargs or by command substitution (``` `` ``` or `$()` in `bash`).